# Axis 1.4 - change to use HTTP/1.1

Tags: http, axis

I have a client trying to connect to a server using Axis 1.4. The Axis Call uses as default HTTP/1.0, but I need version 1.1. I added the property to the Call instance in my class that implements Axis Stub. The method I use creates the Call, sets the property and then invokes the call.

```
call.setProperty(MessageContext.HTTP_TRANSPORT_VERSION, HTTPConstants.HEADER_PROTOCOL_V11);
```

`call.invoke(..)`

I also tried to set the property into the Stub :

```
super._setProperty(MessageContext.HTTP_TRANSPORT_VERSION, HTTPConstants.HEADER_PROTOCOL_V11);
```

But I can see that the POST requests still contain the HTTP/1.0. Is there any other way to force the usage of HTTP/1.1?

In the HTTPSender there is being set this property from the MessageContext and I don't know how to change it.

Answer (score 3):

You could set the properties for the call-requestheader.

```
Hashtable httpSettings = new Hashtable();
httpSettings.put(MessageContext.HTTP_TRANSPORT_VERSION, HTTPConstants.HEADER_PROTOCOL_V11);
_call.setProperty(HTTPConstants.REQUEST_HEADERS, httpSettings);
```

Comment: It's already been a long time, but I recently needed a similar workaround and this answer helped a lot, even though I had to adjust it a little - for me, I had to apply it without the Hashtable, shortening the code to one line like `_call.setProperty(MessageContext.HTTP_TRANSPORT_VERSION, HTTPConstants.HEADER_PROTOCOL_V11);`

Answer (score 0):

The optimal solution is to create the Axis Service with an EngineConfiguration that uses Apache CommonsHTTPSender for transport.

```
SimpleProvider config = new SimpleProvider();
Handler sender = new CommonsHTTPSender();
Handler transport = new SimpleTargetedChain(sender);
config.deployTransport(org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPTransport.DEFAULT_TRANSPORT_NAME, transport);
service = new Service(config);
```